# Writing the user entered data, in a Qt4 UI,to a file

Tags: c++, qt

I created a UI using QtSDK and now i want to get the data entered by the user, in the UI, to a static file. How can I do this? 
For example, I tried:

```
ofstream myfile ("C:\\testcase.txt"); 
if (myfile.is_open()) {
    myfile << "ui->lineEdit->text()";
} else {
    cout << "Unable to open file";
}
```

and it is printing the line within double quotes as it is in the file instead of printing the text entered in lineEdit and if i write

```
myfile << ui -> lineEdit -> text();
```

without the double quotes, the code shows the following error.

```
mainwindow.cpp:198: error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'myfile << QLineEdit::text() const()'
```

How should this be done?

Comment: To answer your question one would need to see more of your code and/or exact message.

Comment: `ofstream myfile ("C:\\testcase.txt");
if (myfile.is_open())
{myfile << ui->lineEdit->text();}                                  else
{cout << "Unable to open file";}` is the part of code where Iam opening the file for writing and the error shown is `C:\QtSDK\QtCreator\bin\test-build-desktop-Qt_4_7_4_for_Desktop_-_MinGW_4_4__Qt_SDK__Debug\..\test\mainwindow.cpp:198: error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'myfile << QLineEdit::text() const()'`

Answer (score 1):

By using double quotes you actually provide a string. The expression within the quotes is not evaluated.

You should use a QTextStream in order to write to a file.

```
QFile file("myfile.txt");
if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    return;

QTextStream filestream(&file);
filestream << ui->lineEdit->text();
```

[Qt Documentation is great, so check it for more details](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qfile.html)

Comment: tried this, there are no compilation errors but the file is not getting created and i fail to understand the reason. Read the documentation as well, did not help.

Comment: Use the force of QDebug, put some debug statements in and trace what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't `<<` `QString` directly, to `std::ostream`. Perhaps you need something like `ui->lineEdit->text()()` or convert it to some standard type otherwise, look up the docs.